# Asterisk: list originated calls (preferably by destination)

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to list awaiting calls into a queue, which were originated by a dialer from my application, a part of the problem is that I'm originating asynchronously.

The only way I think this would be possible is to pass variables to the Originate action and 'core show channel' each channel of my context to retrieve the variables and go from there, but this will be run in small periods with many calls making the load bigger.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Edit: i want the calls that have been originated but not yet dropped in the queue (originate source haven't picked up yet).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `core show channels`, if there is a special command to list awaiting calls `queue show <queue_number>`?

Comment: you can only find the calls that have been dropped in the queue there, i want the calls where the originate source haven't picked up the phone yet.